# cx_Freeze-6.0b1-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel when pip installing

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I have python 3.6 32 bit but it keeps failing to work I have looked around but the solution I have seen don't work, I have tried using 64 bit python but obviously that didn't work either.

I have had this working on past versions of python and cx-freeze but I have upgraded python to 3.6 and I’m trying to install the latest version of cx-freeze as I was having some problems with the last version but this version contains the patch.

Any help?

Comment: Please spend a minute on [question how to](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Why not just try `pip install cx_Freeze` rather than using the .whl file

Comment: What error message are you getting?  Have you got multiple Python versions?

Comment: I am pip installing the file, the error I get is this wheel is not a supported wheel . Any help would greatly be appreciated, thanks